# How to overload Node.js Writable end method in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have created an class extended from Node.js stream library class, doing something special inside this class.

```
import * as stream from 'stream';

export class PipeWritable extends stream.Writable {

   ...

   public end(): void;
   public end(chunk: any, cb?: Function): void;
   public end(chunk: any, encoding?: string, cb?: Function): void {
      super.end();
   }

}
```

This leads to the error:
`error TS2394: Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation`

The argument structure of overloaded methods are copied 1:1 from `@types/node/index.d.ts`.

I know that typescript does not support method overloading, but if you declare modules you can do something like that, as you can see in Node.js module stream:

```
declare module "stream" {
    export class Writable extends Stream implements NodeJS.WritableStream {
        ...
        end(): void;
        end(chunk: any, cb?: Function): void;
        end(chunk: any, encoding?: string, cb?: Function): void;
        ...
    }
}
```

So my question, how I can overwrite the stream.Writable method `end()` ?

Comment: Look at the *Overloads* section in the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html). The key point is that the function implementation's signature is not considered when TypeScript looks for a matching overload. And the function implementation's signature must be compatible with all of the overloads.

Comment: I have studied the [Overloads section in documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) multiple time, but it is strange that you can do something in declaration which is not accepted in implementation. I think it's caused by the fact that module declarations are used as "link" to existing javascript (or native) solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your snippet, these are the overload signatures:

```ts
public end(): void;
public end(chunk: any, cb?: Function): void;
```

And this is the implementation signature:

```ts
public end(chunk: any, encoding?: string, cb?: Function): void {
  super.end();
}
```

The implementation signature is not compatible with either overload signature.

The first overload is not compatible because it has no parameters and the implementation signature has a non-optional `chunk` parameter.

The second overload is not compatible because because its second parameter is a optional `Function` and that's not compatible with an optional `string`.

You must provide an implementation with a signature that is compatible with all of the overloads. For example:

```ts
// The overload signatures:

public end(): void;
public end(chunk: any, cb?: Function): void;
public end(chunk: any, encoding?: string, cb?: Function): void;

// The implementation:

public end(...args: any[]): void {
  super.end(...args);
}
```

Note that when a function has overload signatures, TypeScript matches function calls with the overload signatures only; the implementation signature is **not** considered.

Comment: thanks for response. Maybe you can edit your response and change `super.end(..args);` to `super.end(...args);`. But I have an additional question. Now I would expect, that I can call `this.end(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` because everything (...args: any[] ) is accepted. But your solution only accepts one of the three declarations (as it should be). Can you explain why?

Comment: That's the key point to which I referred in my comment above: if there are overload signatures, the implementation signature is **not** considered when matching a function call with an overload.